# Telit 4G modem LE920-EUG, giving error on http commands, AT#HTTPCFG.. AT#HTTPQRY any http command not working

Tags: sockets, http, at-command, modem, cellular-network

I have the Telit LE920-EUG 4G LTE module. I am trying to execute GET and POST http requests to a remote server. Though the PDP context is activating properly and I have internet access on the SIM that I'm using, I can't seem to be able to connect to a remote server and execute HTTP requests (both POST and GET) from the module.

I have tried two ways, one through direct HTTP commands supported by the module(All commands mentioned in the LE9x0 AT command reference guide), the commands sequence for which is mentioned below, but +CME ERROR: 100 occurs, and it's same for every http command(AT#HHTPQRY, AT#HTTPRCV) that I try to execute.

---

```
AT#SGACT=1,1

#SGACT: 31.81.208.1

OK


AT#HTTPCFG=0,"httpbin.org",80,0,,,0,120,1

+CME ERROR: 100


//No configuration details

AT#HTTPCFG?
+CME ERROR: 100

AT#HTTPCFG=?
+CME ERROR: 100
```

---

I have also tried the GET and POST commands after socket dialing. The socket connects but they are not receiving any data from the server or posting anything onto the server, the connection closes with a NO CARRIER. The command sequence that I'm using is given below

---

```
//Socket Dial

AT#SD=1,0,80,www.m2msupport.net

CONNECT


//GET commands sequence

GET /m2msupport/http_get_test.php HTTP/1.1

Host:www.m2msupport.net

Connection:keep-alive

//Connection closes with No Response
NO CARRIER



//Socket info shows the bytes sent

at#si=1
#SI: 1,86,0,0,0

OK
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, thanks!